# C# WPF (Delete Button) delete item from listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

i'm doing a project in C# WPF that consist in a client management where i add new clients and there are save in a txt document, i have a listview where i can see all clients that have been add, but now i want to implement a delete button where i select a client from the listview and can delete it. i dont now if i'm doing this correct, if someone can help me..,..thanks.

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button_Voltar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
        mw.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button_Listar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Cliente> clientes = new List<Cliente>();

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Rui\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Gestão Clientes Empresas\dadosClientes.txt");

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string[] parts = line.Split(';');
            Cliente a = new Cliente();
            a.Nome = parts[0];
            a.Nif = parts[1];
            a.Morada = parts[2];
            clientes.Add(a);
        }

        listView.ItemsSource = clientes;

    }

    private bool myTextFilter(object item)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox_pesquisa.Text))
            return true;
        var cliente = (Cliente)item;
        return (cliente.Nome.StartsWith(textBox_pesquisa.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

    }

    private void textBox_pesquisa_TextChanged_1(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listView.ItemsSource);
        view.Filter = new Predicate<object>(myTextFilter);
    }

    private void button_Apagar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) \\Delete Button!
    {
        listView.Items.RemoveAt(listView.Items.IndexOf(listView.SelectedItems[0]));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `ObservableCollection`:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Voltar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
        mw.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private readonly ObservableCollection<Cliente> clientes = new ObservableCollection<Cliente>();
    private void button_Listar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Rui\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Gestão Clientes Empresas\dadosClientes.txt");

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string[] parts = line.Split(';');
            Cliente a = new Cliente();
            a.Nome = parts[0];
            a.Nif = parts[1];
            a.Morada = parts[2];
            clientes.Add(a);
        }
        listView.ItemsSource = clientes;
    }

    private bool myTextFilter(object item)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox_pesquisa.Text))
            return true;
        var cliente = (Cliente)item;
        return (cliente.Nome.StartsWith(textBox_pesquisa.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }

    private void textBox_pesquisa_TextChanged_1(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listView.ItemsSource);
        view.Filter = new Predicate<object>(myTextFilter);
    }

    private void button_Apagar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Cliente client = listView.SelectedItem as Cliente;
        if(client != null)
            clientes.Remove(client);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! its a good way to solved but one thing missed me to say its that when i delete the client it must delete to in the txt file..if that not happen every time i list the clients there will show all again, do i need do update the client list every time i delete a client?

Comment: Deleting it from the text file is the same thing as writing all items but the removed one back to the text file. How to do this is a different question.